# How to add content script to iframe document programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing some diagnostic tool and trying to create chrome extension for it. What I have is a page with an iframe. The iframe contains site that is laying on `diffrent domain`.

What I need is a communication between those two sites. What I figured out is that I can simply add an `content script` to each of those documents (to iframe document and my top window document) and set a communication between them by the `background script` and message flow.

The problem is that I don't know what is the address of the document in the iframe right now, users can put multiple diffrent pages into iframe. Because of this I cannot add `content script` using `manifest.json` file, because I do not know what to put into `matches` property.

I tried to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` method with `allFrames` flag set to true. It worked fine when the iframe document was on the same domain as top window document, but when it's on diffrent domain it does not add `content script` to frame document.

The problem is strange, because if I know the iframe url on design time then I can add those scripts just like that from manifest file...

**How can I add content script to iframe document in such situation?**

I will also tell you that I have permission to every page in my `manifest.json` file. It lokks like this: `"permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/"]`. Additonal obstacle is that I cannot ingerate in iframe document content, it's third-party code.

Any ideas? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How did you verify that content scripts are not executed x-domain? AFAIK, `executeScript` + `allFrames:true` executes a content script in the top window and all frames beneath. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I'v put the script like `alert(window.location.href)` and get only url of the top window.

Comment: And you're running the code *after* the page has fully loaded? If you open the background page, and use `chrome.tabs.query({active:true});` to get the tabID, then `chrome.tabs.executeScript(<tabIdHere>, {code:'alert(location.href);'})`, how many alerts do you get?

Comment: Wow.. this is great.. I put `setTimeout` to call `executeScript` after the frame loads and now it works perfectly. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `Rob W` comment the problem was the timing. I was trying to inject script into iframe before it was loaded. I've used `onload` event on the iframe to determine the moment when the `executeScript` method should be called.

Now everything works fine. Thanks Rob.